# Custom management commands lost after deployment

Tags: python, django

Please forgive my ignorance if I say something weird, I'm pretty new to Django yet.

I'm facing a strange problem where when sending a current django folder to a production server, some of the management commands that I have in local are gone in the server.

Both in my local machine and server are using virtualenv. Locally everything works well, so when I run this custom command:

```
 python manage.py surfspots_load_nowcast --settings=opencoast.settings.dev
```

I get the expected output.

This is the folder structure, by the way:

[image]

This are my installed apps in base.py settings file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # 'django.contrib.auth',
    # 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    # 'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.gis',
    # 'social.apps.django_app.default',
    'django_extensions',
    'opencoast.java',
    # 'opencoast.core',
    'opencoast.scrappers.surfspots_es',
)
```

This is the contents of dev.py, which, by the way, is the one I'm using also in the server:

```
from .base import *  # NOQA

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'supersecretpassword'
    }
}


INSTALLED_APPS += (
    'opencoast.tests.integration',
)
```

And this are the contents of prod.py:

```
DEBUG = False

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    # TODO
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER': 'db_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'supersecretpassword'
    }
}
```

Now I simply zip the whole contents of the root folder, send it to my server, unzip, create the virtualenv, db, etc, but when I activate my virtualenv in the server and run the command, I always face this problem:

```
(django)root@infra:~/scripts/django# python manage.py surfspots_load_nowcast --settings=opencoast.settings.dev
Unknown command: 'surfspots_load_nowcast'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

Looking back at my local app, running manage.py I see at the bottom of the list this:

```
[gis]
inspectdb
ogrinspect

[staticfiles]
collectstatic
findstatic
runserver

[surfspots_es]
surfspots_load_nowcast
surfspots_load_spots
```

While in the server:

```
[gis]
inspectdb
ogrinspect

[staticfiles]
collectstatic
findstatic
runserver
```

I've tried:

```
manage.py checkout
manage.py validate
```

Everything seems ok, also

```
manage.py migrate
manage.py runserver
```

And everything seems to be working, is just that the command is not working at all, I've read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/) and [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/) throughly, but nothing I've tried seems to be working

Any idea what I'm missing here??

**EDIT**: As suggested, I've tried this also this, which does not seem to produce any error:

```
(django)root@infra:~/scripts/django# python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.4.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. 
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: from django.conf import settings

In [2]: print settings.INSTALLED_APPS
('django.contrib.messages', 'django.contrib.staticfiles',   'django.contrib.gis', 'django_extensions', 'opencoast.java', 'opencoast.core', 'opencoast.scrappers.surspots_es', 'opencoast.tests.integration')

In [3]: import opencoast.scrappers.surfspots_es

In [4]:
```

**FINAL EDIT:** After looking at the installed apps locally and in server and noticing that they were different, I've rezipped the folder again and sent it, removed .pyc files just in case and now it seems to work...don't really know why yet...

Comment: did you check the diff in your prod settings and your local ? May be the package is not in installed_apps ?

Comment: Hello karthikr, what package do you mean? I've used pip freeze to create the requirements.txt and then recreate the same virtualenv...they are exactly the same...

Comment: I meant surfspots_es

Comment: How does your "settings.dev" and "settings.prod" look like? Do they override INSTALLED_APPS ?

Comment: Hello @ZZY, I've edited the post and you can see both dev.py and prod.py, although I'm currently using only dev.py...

Comment: @karthikr How can I check that? I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean...

Comment: You may try to enter "manage.py shell", then `from django.conf import settings`    `print settings.INSTALLED_APPS`    `import opencoast.scrappers.surfspots_es`, check whether INSTALL_APPS is correct and whether the import is successful

Comment: @ZZY See my edited response, output seems correct nope?